# Roles.CreateRole() creates a new database inside App_Data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, roles, membership-provider

What could be the reason for `Roles.CreateRole("admin")` creating a new local database inside `App_Data`, if my default membership provider is set to use a connection to an actual SQL Server?

I have a connection string like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MembershipDbConnection" 
     connectionString="Server=.;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;User Id=*;Password=*" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and a membership provider defined like this:

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add
      name="SqlProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
      connectionStringName="MembershipDbConnection"  <-- this is the connection
      />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

The weird thing is, there is an `aspnetdb` database (populated with tables) in my SQL Server, and if I use `Membership.GetAllUsers()`, I get the users in that table without problems. Login also works as expected. But `Roles.CreateRole` creates a new database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure the Role manager section if you want to use roles. It is likely you are picking up the inherited RoleManager section that is using a different connection string.

Comment: +1 Thanks. There was a line `<roleManager enabled="true" />` with no provider set explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't supply "applicationName" attribute in "membership" and "roleManager" tags in Web.Config. Here is an example: -

```
<membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MembershipDbConnection"  applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>


<roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="MembershipDbConnection" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
        <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mansoor Gee's answer provides an excellent template to follow.
Here's a link to documentation of what, and how, should be implemented in the web.config to enable RoleManager:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms164660(v=vs.100).aspx

Hopefully this will add some context to future readers, as I needed some when I first came across this answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Sam I AM, Good idea, I'll try and modify my answer to better explain the (hopefully) helpfulness of this link. Thanks for the tip!